# How can I add a context menu to UI element in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, maui

The code below is not working, Error XLS0415 The attachable property 'ContextActions' was not found in type 'Grid' and "The type 'FlyoutBase' was not found"

```
<Grid.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Text="Test"/>
    <MenuItem Text="Test 2"/>
</Grd.ContextActions>
```

```
<FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
```

Comment: Like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menubar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ContextActions` can only be used in a `ListView` cell (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem)). This enables a swipe to reveal some buttons on iOS and long press context menu on Android, but only for those cells.

If you want to use this on other elements you can have a look at [SwipeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview).

For desktop right-clicks we're working on context menus like those right now and they should be ready in .NET 7.

Comment: This may not be the place to ask this but why only desktop? Android has had the PopupMenu for a while and it is what I had to resort to using in a MAUI android app. Its a little silly I had to make a "ContextMenuService" which just creates a new PopupMenu and calls Show(). The result is the exact kind of context menu we are used to 20+ years on desktop environments and is becoming more and more popular on mobile. The ListView ContextActions are just plain bad (on Android).

Comment: I think it's also implemented for Android

Comment: This is now in the official documentation: "A context menu, often known as a right-click menu, offers contextual commands that are specific to the control being clicked on. In .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI), a context menu can be added to any control that derives from Element, on Mac Catalyst and Windows. This includes all pages, layouts, and views." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/context-menu?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @GeraldVersluis If one is stuck with .net6, what is the preferable way to achieve working context menus in MAUI on Windows (excluding ListView)? I don't understand how SwipeView would help.

Comment: `SwipeView` is still unavailable on Windows

Comment: SwipeView isn’t really a desktop element. We have context menus (right click) on Windows now: https://youtu.be/o35BEuIC-uA

Comment: How do I get information about which list view item is long-pressed or on which list view item the context menu was opened?